# Failed to add android platform to ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, platform

How can I add the Android platform to an Ionic project?

I created an ionic project, run it using the (`ionic serve --lab`) and it runs well in the browser. Then wanted to **add android platform** to it after setting the path in the system variable very well with a confirmation of running a command (android) in the cmd and it opened the sdk (However for eclipse).

The run the command for adding android platform as (ionic platform add android)
and it failed, Then aslo run with (***ionic cordova platform add android***) and also failed too.

It displayed the following error:

```
ERROR Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android~6.3.0
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android~6.3.0
probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed woth exit code ENOENT
```

May you help me. 
I will be glad for your response.
***Thanks***

Comment: there seems to have little compatibility issues with 6.3.0 (at least for now), for some people, updating the SDK fixed it, or else, go back to a previous version as stated in Vishnu's answer (6.2.3 should work too)

Answer (score 0):

Please do specify the version of android you want to add, for example:ionic platform add android@6.0.0, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please do restore the state of our current application by:

```
ionic state restore
```

This solved my problem